# Why are the 5Ghz band of my routers not visible from my DLink X-treme DWA-552 N PCI adapter?

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I bought a [DLink DWA-552 PCI N-band adapter](http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=531) and it is able to see my [DLINK-615 N-band](http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=DIR-615) without a problem.

I bought a [Netgear 3700N](http://netgear.com/Products/WirelessRouter/WirelessRoutersforHighPerformance/WNDR3700.aspx)  and [Linksys WRT-610N](http://homestore.cisco.com/en-us/outlet/Routers/linksys-WRT610N-RM_stcVVproductId83108078VVcatId543906VVviewprod.htm)  and my dlink adapter is not able to see the 5Ghz band on either router.  I am only able to see the 2.4Ghz band , even at very close range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it is because the DLink DWA-552 adapter doesn't support the 5 GHz band.

Looking at the specs for the adapter it says it supports IEEE 802.11n and IEEE 802.11g which is the first clue. Usually wireless devices which support the 5 GHz band also include support for 802.11a. Since this adapter does not, it calls into question whether it supports 5 GHz.

Then I noticed the next line or so down in the specs is `Wireless Frequency Range: 2.4GHz to 2.4835GHz`. Again, I don't see any claims for support for 5 GHz here.

Not all 802.11n adapters out there support both the 2.4 and 5 GHz bands. This looks to be one of them. It's one way to cut manufacturing costs, I suppose.

BTW, I don't understand the reference to you DLINK-615. The other two routers you mentioned are both simultaneous dual band routers. But the DLINK-615 only supports only the 2.4 GHz band. Right?

Comment: that explains it then. It does appear that I am getting draft N-band bandwidth via the 2.4Ghz spectrum and so your comments validate what i am experiencing.  When I bought this adapter that was sure misleading.  Makes me want to return it.

Comment: FWIW, a quick way to check if a wireless client adapter supports 5 GHz is to check for 802.11a support. If you don't see it, either look closer or just pass on the adapter. I suppose it's possible to build an adapter which supports 5 GHz in 802.11n but does not support 802.11a. But so far I haven't seen one that does this. (Then again, I really don't get out as much as I used to ... ;-)